# Help identifying component in simple LED circuit

Tags: led, switches, identification, surface-mount

I was hoping someone could identify what (type) of component is used in this LED circuit that runs off a 3V coincell battery. It's rather simple: press the button and the LED switches on indefinitely until the button is pressed again. Is it some type of relay?

[image: pic] [image]

Comment: If you press on it, does it 'detent' a bit like a switch would?

Comment: @jonk pressing the yellow button feels like it is a a mechanical switch. if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I just wanted to be absolutely sure. It's a button, of course, and the black blob is just a cheap way of protecting a chip on that board. It's probably a simple IC circuit or even a cheap MCU, possibly, whose only job is to monitor the switch and operate the LED. Without subjecting the chip to a very detailed scan, there's no way to tell more.

Comment: why are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this should be clear enough: -

[image]

> **Is it some type of relay?**

No, it isn't (that's for sure).

Comment: Any ideas as to what type of IC it is, given the circuit description?

Comment: Some sort of toggle circuit, no doubt.  There are fancy purpose-made ICs that include debounce as well but I don't think this one has it.  There also might be current limiting built in but as it's running off a coin cell they could probably get away without it.  It might even just be a flip flop.

Comment: @tristenlee I could speculate but, what's the point? Where does that help?

Comment: If it isn't working right, and a new battery doesn't fix it, then the chip likely failed.